# JPanel is not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I copied the examples straight from the book. The code is supposed to draw a couple things on the JFrame, but nothing shows up(other than the JFrame) Here is the class with the main method

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaApplication24 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(480,270);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    NewClass panel = new NewClass();

    frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);

    }
```

Here is a subclass of JPanel

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class NewClass extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,100,100);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(50,50,100,100);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Hello",200,200);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(240,40,100,30);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue #1

Your `NewClass` should provide sizing hints which the layout manager (`BorderLayout` in this case) can make decisions about how best to layout your component.

You should also be calling `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting, otherwise you will end up with no end of rendering artifacts appearing

```
public class NewClass extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Hello", 200, 200);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(240, 40, 100, 30);

    }
}
```

> I copied the examples straight from the book

I hoping you just made some minor mistakes, otherwise I'd be concerned about the validity of the book :P

You should also be starting your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this tends to solve issues which can appear on different platforms...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new NewClass());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

## Issue #2

You should not make the UI visible until AFTER you've established it, instead of

```
frame.setVisible(true);
NewClass panel = new NewClass();

frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
```

Use something more like...

```
NewClass panel = new NewClass();
frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);    
frame.setVisible(true);
```

There are ways you can trigger and update after the frame is made visible, but this is just the simplest fix

Comment: one thing i did realise now is that the drawn images only show when I set the dimensions for setSize() to something large like setSize(1500,1500);